# Testing Spring Boot Library Modules

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, automated-tests

I got a multi module project where not every module is actually an application but a lot of them are libs. Those libs are doing the major work and I want to test them where they are implemented. The current dependencies of the libs:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
```

In the main source is a class with `@Configuration` and a single bean:

```
@Bean public String testString() { return "A Test String"; }
```

I got 2 test classes:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles({"default", "test"}) 
public class Test1 {  

    @Test
    public void conextLoaded() {
    }
}
```

-

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles({"default", "test"}) 
public class Test2 {  
    @Autowired
    private String testString; 

    @Test
    public void conextLoaded() {
    }
}
```

The first test works. The second does not. There is not `@SpringBootApplication` anywhere in that project so in the same package as the Tests I added a test configuration:

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.to.config") 
public class LibTestConfiguration {
}
```

And it does not work. Same for classes that are `@Service`. They are not in the context. How can I make it behave like a normal Spring boot application without it actually beeing one and load the configs and contexts from the configurations files I need? The default and test profile share most of their properties (for now) and I want them to be loaded like I would start a tomcat.

Comment: Ideally, your library components should be unit-testable.

Comment: Thats the plan but they will still be services and components with specific testconfigs. The alternative would be to initialize the Services all my self but that doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: Are you familiar with test mocks? Usually you test your services *one at a time*, mocking out each of their dependencies as you go.

Comment: Yes but what is for example if the dependency is a database and I have a complex query to test? I wanna test the spring data repositories too. And they are created by spring boot at runtime normally. I got  an elasticsearch index in there too. And those queries tend to get complicated very fast and also tend to break here and there. I understand the isolation part and for most services you are right I can just inject the dependencies myself (which is mostly string configs) at test runtime. But for those implemenentations provided by spring I don't see how to (still prefer an external testconf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I switched to JUnit 5 and made it kinda work... So if you want to test Database stuff:

```
@DataMongoTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles({"default", "test"})
class BasicMongoTest { ... }
```

- Lets you autowire all repositories and mongo template
- Initializes with apllicaton.yml config
- Does NOT initialize or configure interceptors

---

Full application context test if you have a class with `@SpringBootApplication` in your classpath (Can be an empty test main in your test context)

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles({"default", "test"})
public class FullContextTest { ... }
```

- Initializes the full context with all configs and beans
- Should not be done if not necessary as it loads all the application context and kinda defeats the purpose of unit tests to only activate whats needed.

---

Test only specific components and configs:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Config1.class, Component1.class})
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles({"default", "test"})
public class SpecificComponentsTest { ... }
```

- Initializes the context with only the Config1 and Component1 classes. Component1 and all beans in Config1 can be autowired.

Comment: Do note, that 
`@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`
is redundant when using `@SpringBootTest`

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved adding in root test package path a `SpringAppConfiguration` class

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SpringAppConfiguration {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringAppConfiguration.class, args);
    }
}
```