# Testing library that is using spring boot 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have a library and I want to implement an integrations test for the Repository (only an example for a more complex case).

To reproduce the case, I used [this official example](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-jpa/tree/main/complete), but removing the [`AccessingDataJpaApplication.java`](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-jpa/blob/main/complete/src/main/java/com/example/accessingdatajpa/AccessingDataJpaApplication.java) class because I will expose it as a library and not as application.

Now that the repo does not have the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation, [the test](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-jpa/blob/main/complete/src/test/java/com/example/accessingdatajpa/CustomerRepositoryTests.java) will fail because can not inject the [`private CustomerRepository customers;`](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-jpa/blob/968981c6a08362eab5ef864b86418347e959bb1d/complete/src/test/java/com/example/accessingdatajpa/CustomerRepositoryTests.java#L34)

How to reproduce the case:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-jpa.git
cd gs-accessing-data-jpa/complete
mvn test # Working
rm src/main/java/com/example/accessingdatajpa/AccessingDataJpaApplication.java
mvn test # not working
```

**The question is, which is the right way to annotate this test if it is not an application?**

I tried annotating the test with few combinations like:

- Adding `@SpringBootTest`:

  ```java
  @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
  @DataJpaTest
  @SpringBootTest
  public class CustomerRepositoryTests {
  }
  ```

  The error looks like try to say that there are multiple inizializations, I suppose that each annotation try to do its own:

  ```
    [ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.067 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.example.accessingdatajpa.CustomerRepositoryTests
    [ERROR] com.example.accessingdatajpa.CustomerRepositoryTests  Time elapsed: 0.067 s  <<< ERROR!
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class [com.example.accessingdatajpa.CustomerRepositoryTests]: [@org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper.class), @org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.class)]
  ```
- Setting only `@SpringBootTest`

  ```java
  @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
  @SpringBootTest
  public class CustomerRepositoryTests {}
  ```

  Then I can not use the `TestEntityManager` and still is not able to inject the repository

  ```
  17:29:01.951 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [CustomerRepositoryTests]: using SpringBootContextLoader
  17:29:01.954 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [com.example.accessingdatajpa.CustomerRepositoryTests]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
  17:29:01.954 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils - Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [com.example.accessingdatajpa.CustomerRepositoryTests]: CustomerRepositoryTests does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
  17:29:01.964 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Using ContextCustomizers for test class [CustomerRepositoryTests]: [ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer, DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer, MockitoContextCustomizer, TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer, DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer, PropertyMappingContextCustomizer, Customizer]
  [ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.117 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.example.accessingdatajpa.CustomerRepositoryTests
  [ERROR] com.example.accessingdatajpa.CustomerRepositoryTests  Time elapsed: 0.116 s  <<< ERROR!
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Class.getName()" because "found" is null
  ```
- And `@SpringBootTest(classes = {CustomerRepository.class})`:

  ```java
  @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
  @SpringBootTest(classes = {CustomerRepository.class})
  public class CustomerRepositoryTests {}
  ```

  With error:

  ```
  org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.example.accessingdatajpa.CustomerRepositoryTests': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customers': No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.accessingdatajpa.CustomerRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
  ```

Maybe the solution is related to `[com.example.accessingdatajpa.CustomerRepositoryTests]: CustomerRepositoryTests does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.`. But how to do it exactly?

BTW: I found [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58175467/testing-spring-boot-library-modules) in Stackoverflow, but it is not working. Maybe because the Spring version.

Comment: The first one fails because you should use or `@DataJpaTest` (for a test slice) **or** `@SpringBootTest` for a full blown integration test. Adding both to a testcase doesn't make sense. Your tests fail because there is no `@SpringBootConfiguration` class to be found because you removed the application. You now basically have a regular Spring application without Spring Boot features. So you will need to manually configure your testing by providing the configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but this is exactly what I explain (I don't have SpringBootTest because it's not an application and first case is not working because I have multiple initialisations). My question is about how to test it and which set of annotations I need. I expected the last one working.

Comment: Why would the last one work as that still is an `@SpringBootTest` which cannot find the class with `@SpringBootApplication` to inspect it to know what to instantiate. (Or the `@SpringBootConfiguration` that is), without that ther will be no auto configuration.

Comment: Could I use @SpringBootConfiguration someplace in the Test to enable the Spring Boot autoconfiguration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the working approach:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class CustomerRepositoryTests {

   @SpringBootApplication
   static class TestConfig {}

   @Autowired
   private TestEntityManager entityManager;

   @Autowired
   private CustomerRepository customers;

   @Test
   public void testFindByLastName() {
      ......

   }
}
```

So each test class will autoconfigure the context using Spring Boot.

Reference: [spring-data-examples repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/main/jpa/showcase/src/test/java/example/springdata/jpa/showcase/AbstractShowcaseTest.java)